# Powershell rows to columns

Tags: powershell

I need Powershell script to transpose rows to columns.
I have this data:

```
State   PC    Time
Open    PC1   00:09:16
Close   PC1   00:09:21
Open    PC2   00:09:48
Open    PC3   00:12:50
Open    PC4   00:12:50
Open    PC1   00:13:42
Close   PC3   00:15:14
Close   PC5   00:20:07
Close   PC2   00:20:08
Close   PC1   00:22:24
```

and I want this result:

```
PC    Open       Close
PC1   00:09:16   00:09:21
PC2   00:09:48   00:20:08
PC3   00:12:50   00:15:14
PC4   00:12:50
PC1   00:13:42   00:22:24
```

So far I tried:

```
$data | Group PC |ForEach-Object {
    $entries = $_.Group
    [pscustomobject]@{
        PC = $entries[0].PC
        Open = ($entries |Where-Object State -eq Open).Time
        Close = ($entries |Where-Object State -eq Close).Time
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work with duplicate PC names. In this example, PC1 appears 2 times, PC4 has no Close time, and PC5 is abandoned due to missing Open time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to correlate the Open-Close pairs to get the output you describe, you'll need to:

- Sort the entries in each group by time
- Skip consecutive state events to avoid duplicate timestamps
- Check whether the last Open entry is missing a Close time

You can do so like this:

```
$data | Group-Object PC | ForEach-Object {
    # Sort entries in group by timestamp
    $currentEntry, $remainingEntries = $_.Group | Sort-Object Time
    while ($currentEntry -and $currentEntry.State -eq 'Close') {
        # Skip unmatched close events at the start of the list
        $currentEntry, $remainingEntries = $remainingEntries
    }

    # Scan through the remaining entries to discover the next close event,
    # and then rinse-repeat until we've processed all entries
    foreach ($nextEntry in $remainingEntries) {
        if (-not$currentEntry) {
            if ($nextEntry.State -eq 'Open') {
                # start of a new pair
                $currentEntry = $nextEntry        
            }
            # otherwise skip unmatched Close entries
            continue
        }
      
        if ($nextEntry.State -eq 'Close') {
            # we found the next Close entry, output the pair
            [pscustomobject]@{
                PC    = $currentEntry.PC
                Open  = $currentEntry.Time
                Close = $nextEntry.Time
            }
            # and get ready to start over
            $currentEntry = $null
        }
    }

    if ($currentEntry) {
        # We have a trailing Open entry with no Close, output as-is
        [pscustomobject]@{
            PC    = $currentEntry.PC
            Open  = $currentEntry.Time
            Close = ''
        }
    }
} | Sort-Object Open, PC
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is listed chronologically, this should work:

```
$open = @{};
$data | % {
  if ($_.state -eq "Open" ) { $open[$_.pc] = $_.time }
  if ($_.state -eq "Close") {
    if ($open[$_.pc]) {
      $o = $open[$_.pc];
      [pscustomobject]@{
        "PC"    = $_.pc
        "Open"  = $o
        "Close" = $_.time
      }
    }
    $open.remove($_.pc);
  }
} -End { 
  $open.Keys | % {
    [pscustomobject]@{
      "PC"    = $_
      "Open"  = $open[$_]
      "Close" = ""
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
PC  Open     Close
--  ----     -----
PC1 00:09:16 00:09:21
PC3 00:12:50 00:15:14
PC2 00:09:48 00:20:08
PC1 00:13:42 00:22:24
PC4 00:12:50
```

This can be sorted by open time and pc value like this:

```
... | Sort Open, PC
```

Output:

```
PC  Open     Close
--  ----     -----
PC1 00:09:16 00:09:21
PC2 00:09:48 00:20:08
PC3 00:12:50 00:15:14
PC4 00:12:50
PC1 00:13:42 00:22:24
```

Comment: The output doesn't look like OPs expected output.

Comment: @zett42: true, I have converted the solution to use a hashtable instead, which produces the same output, albeit not in the same order unless it gets sorted